# How to windowing the kafka stream events?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am currently working on kafka stream project that try to count for example the word "cat" in the sentence that was produced for every 5 seconds (one sentence produced per second) and send back the answer in form like cat xxx (number of occurrence in past 5 seconds). I am new to the java but after searching for similar problem I figured out the code (based on kafka stream word count demo) but it runs with an error.

The Java Script

```
package org.apache.kafka.streams.examples.wordcount;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.WindowedSerdes;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public final class WordCountDemo {

    public static final String INPUT_TOPIC = "streams-plaintext-input";
    public static final String OUTPUT_TOPIC = "streams-wordcount-output";

    static Properties getStreamsConfig(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            try (final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0])) {
                props.load(fis);
            }
            if (args.length > 1) {
                System.out.println("Warning: Some command line arguments were ignored. This demo only accepts an optional configuration file.");
            }
        }
        props.putIfAbsent(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-wordcount");
        props.putIfAbsent(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.putIfAbsent(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
        props.putIfAbsent(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.putIfAbsent(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

        props.putIfAbsent(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return props;
    }

    static void createWordCountStream(final StreamsBuilder builder) {
        final KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC);

        final KTable<String, Long> counts = source.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).split("\\W+")))
            .groupBy((key, value) -> value)
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
            .count()
            .filter((key, value) -> value.equals("cat"));
            

        counts.toStream().to(OUTPUT_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Properties props = getStreamsConfig(args);

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        createWordCountStream(builder);
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-wordcount-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

An error

```
C:\src\kafka-2.7.0-src>START /b /wait cmd /C "gradle assemble -x clients:javadoc streams:test-utils:javadoc streams:streams-scala:scaladoc connect:mirror-client:javadoc connect:api:javadoc core:javadoc core:compileScala"

> Configure project :
Building project 'core' with Scala version 2.13.3
Building project 'streams-scala' with Scala version 2.13.3

> Task :streams:examples:compileJava FAILED
C:\src\kafka-2.7.0-src\streams\examples\src\main\java\org\apache\kafka\streams\examples\wordcount\WordCountDemo.java:86: error: incompatible types: KTable<Windowed<String>,Long> cannot be converted to KTable<String,Long>
            .filter((key, value) -> value.equals("cat"));
                   ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':streams:examples:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
156 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 152 up-to-date
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to edit/compile the Kafka source code? The examples are meant to be copied outside of the project (although, I think they are used for regression tests)

Answer (score 0):

The error says your types are incorrect at the point when you filter.

If you want to filter the table, use `filter` before the `groupBy` rather than after the count because the "value" of the count operation is a Long, not a String

If you want to filter the output topic only, use `toStream().filter`

---

Alternatively, don't `filter` the stream/table for a specific word and instead use a StateStore for selectively looking for `"cat"` and any other word in the KTable

Comment: I have tried to use filter before group by but it doesn't works and I want to filter out the output message not the topic. However all I can see is the ".windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))" is the problem because I can run the script without any error by comment this line (the outcome print out every time it receive the sentence which not delay the 5 seconds loop) and it seems like the problem is the data type output of windowed method is not compatible with other method. Could you help me more on this?

Comment: If you're using console producer, you cant filter data there, so `INPUT_TOPIC` will always have the strings needed. You need to run the Streams code while producing data for the time-windows to work; you woudn't expect the window to work with existing data in the topic, or waiting longer than the window _after_ you've produced the data for the window to capture anything. You can adjust the window, if this is not what you want https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing

Comment: The problem is not "compatibility", but rather the order in which you run your code, not how its written (the compiler errors are different from the runtime behavior)